# How to open all the infowindows as default when map loaded?

Tags: maps, marker, infowindow

I've been trying to open all marker's infoWindows whenever map is loaded at first. However "infoWindow.open(map, marker[i]);" or some other variations doesnt work. Even I tried another for loop inside it but couldn't done it. So you got any suggestion about that?

```
var spLocations_length = spLocations.length;

// Display multiple markers on a map
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker, i;

var iconCounter = 0;
// Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
for (i = 0; i < spLocations_length; i++) {
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(spLocations[i][1], spLocations[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        title: spLocations[i][0],
        icon: icons[iconCounter]
    });
    // Allow each marker to have an info window
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));

   // IT DOESN'T WORK FOR OPEN ALL MARKERS INFOWINDOWS WHEN MAP LOADED
    infoWindow.open(map, marker[i]);



    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found out a solution but that is indirect way.

Instead, opening all infowindows, I've used "**Marker Label**" solution.

**The trick is using "Marker Icon" image as a background instead of infowindow container.**

Thus, label text is changing dynamically through the for loop and array.

I hope that snippet helps someone.

```
// locations Array contains location coords and titles //
var locations[.....]; 

for (i = 0; i < locations.lenght; i++) {

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: locations[i][0],
    icon: "https.......",
    index: i,
    label: {
      text: locations.length + locations[i][0] "This is text",
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: "14px",
      fontFamily: "Roboto, Arial, sans-serif",
      fontWeight: "bold"
    }

  });
}
```

Google Source Here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels